# Does Thrift have async server side method definitions for Java?

Tags: java, asynchronous, thrift

I can wire up an HsHaServer and Async client in Java and get it all running swimmingly. The problem is that there doesn't seem to be an async interface for truly async services. The service interface is something like

public TSomeReposonse doStuff( TSomeParams params );

which requires me to block inside of doStuff until am ready to return TSomeResponse

There is an Async.Iface

public void doStuff( TSomeParams params, AsyncMethodCallback[AsyncClient.doStuff_call] );

but it looks like that is only for the client side. There doesn't seem to be a way to pass a value into the callback. Am I right in this? If I want true server-side asynchrony do I need to implement my own client/server with something like netty?

Thanks,
Andrew

Comment: Poops. Thats what I thought. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew I have the same question today . Does this still hold true ?

Answer (score 2):

This question is pretty old (there's probably a badge for this), but just in case this is relevant to someone, the answer is yes. It is called Asynchronous Processing - see here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/THRIFT-1972

It uses the same interface an async client would use.

There is an almost ridiculous lack of documentation about this though.

Comment: Still works as far as I can tell: https://postimg.cc/fS7rNDJX

Comment: You also have to use the corresponding non-blocking server classes, e.g. `TNonblockingServerSocket` and `TNonblockingServer`. Using the regular blocking classes with an async processor seems to result in requests getting stuck. Additionally using the non-blocking server apparently [requires using `TFramedTransport`](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/4637f6d5f8df752291f5e3c8923824e819a2b60f/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/server/AbstractNonblockingServer.java#L349).